# R ggplot2 adding function to a histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics

I am trying to add this function curve to a histogram. Individually, they work. But when I try to put them on the same graph, the function messes up... I can't seem to figure out how to get them together.

```
# make dataframe for ggplot (can use random numbers from 0 to 10 to simulate x)
c= data.frame(x= x, cx= c(seq(from= 0.001, to= 10, by= 0.001)))
```

x and cx have the same number of data points.

```
# function for curve (alpha and beta are just constants set at 0.5)
fx= function(x){
    (beta^alpha)/((x+beta)^(alpha+1)*gamma(alpha))
}
```

When either the geom_histogram or the stat_function is commented out, the graph works correctly.

```
# graph code
h_x= ggplot(data= NULL) +
    geom_histogram(data= c, aes(x= x, y= ..density..), binwidth= 0.2, col= "purple", fill= "yellow") +
    stat_function(fun= fx, data= c, aes(x= cx)) +
    coord_cartesian(xlim= c(0:10)) +
    labs(title= "Figure 03", x= "x")
plot(h_x)
```

Curve by itself

[image: curve by itself];

Histogram and curve together

[image: histogram and curve together]

Comment: To make your example work I used `set.seed(47); cc = data.frame(x= runif(10000, 0, 10), cx = c(seq(from= 0.001, to= 10, by= 0.001)))` and `fx = function(x, alpha = 0.5, beta = 0.5, gamma = 0.5){
    (beta^alpha)/((x+beta)^(alpha+1)*gamma(alpha))
}`. (I renamed the data `cc` because `c` is already the name of the most common function). With those changes to make it run, the graph looks fine. If you still have problems, please edit the code so that the problems can be reproduced. For now I am voting to close as "typo/not reproducible".

Comment: My guess is that somewhere you changed one (at least) of your definitions of `alpha`, `beta`, or `gamma`. This is why it is good practice to treat function parameters as arguments rather than having them go out looking for values in the global environment.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Gregor, I made some changes to your code and the graph looks OK.
I hope it can help you.

```
set.seed(1)
x <- rgamma(10000,1)
df1 <- data.frame(x= x, cx= c(seq(from= 0.001, to= 10, by= 0.001)))

beta <- alpha <- 0.5
fx <- function(x) {
    print(str(x))
    (beta^alpha)/((x+beta)^(alpha+1)*gamma(alpha))
}

# graph code
h_x <- ggplot(data=df1) +
    geom_histogram(aes(x= x, y= ..density..), binwidth= 0.2, col= "purple", fill= "yellow") +
    stat_function(fun=fx, aes(x=cx), lwd=1) +
    coord_cartesian(xlim= c(0:10)) +
    labs(title= "Figure 03", x="x")
plot(h_x)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help! I ended up figuring out the problem... It's because there was some large values (greater than 100) for my x values, when I removed these points, the graph looked much better!

But now my graph looks like this:

[image: graph without a smooth curve]

```
n= 10000
 i= 1
 alpha= 0.5
 beta= 0.5
 x= matrix(data= 5, nrow= n)
 lambda= matrix(data= 1.5, nrow= n)

 while (i < n) {
   x[i+1]= rexp(1, rate= lambda[i])
   lambda[i+1]= (x[i+1]+beta)^(alpha+1)*(lambda[i]^alpha)*exp(-lambda[i]*(x[i+1]+beta))

if ((lambda[i+1] < 0.00001) || (lambda[i+1] > 10)) {
  while ((lambda[i+1] < 0.00001) || (lambda[i+1] > 10)) {
    x[i+1]= rexp(1, rate= lambda[i])
    lambda[i+1]= (x[i+1]+beta)^(alpha+1)*(lambda[i]^alpha)*exp(-lambda[i]*(x[i+1]+beta))
  }
}
i= i+1
}

# data frame:
df4= data.frame(x= x[x<100], cx= c(seq(from= 0.011, to= 10, by= 0.001)))  

# graph (same function (fx) from first post):
h_x= ggplot(data= df4) +
    geom_histogram(aes(x= x, y= ..density..), binwidth= 0.2, col= "purple", fill= "yellow") +
    stat_function(fun= fx) +
    coord_cartesian(xlim= c(0:10)) +
    labs(title= "Figure 03", x= "x")
  plot(h_x)
```

Is there any way to make it a smooth curve? I tried scale_x_continuous but to no avail...

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out again.... I needed to add the argument 'n=10000' to my stat_function!